# Flink rest api error: Request did not match expected format JarRunRequestBody

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-flink

Trying to run a flink job remotely using the below rest api but its throwing error

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '
{
    "type": "object",
    "id": "urn:jsonschema:org:apache:flink:runtime:webmonitor:handlers:JarRunRequestBody",
    "properties": {
    "programArgsList" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : [
        "input-kafka-server": "****",
        "input-kafka-topics": "****",
        "input-job-name": "****"
      
    }
  }
}
' http://x.x.x.x:8081/jars/810ac968-5d5f-450d-aafc-22655238d617.jar/run
```

**{"errors":["Request did not match expected format JarRunRequestBody."]}**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The description of the request body for the jar run handler you find [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/monitoring/rest_api.html) is the [JSON schema specification](https://json-schema.org/) of the jar run message. What you need to specify in your request are only the `properties` and not the `"type"` and `"id"` fields. Thus, your request should look like:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '
{
  "programArgsList" : [
    "--input-kafka-server",
    "value-input-kafka-server",
    "--input-kafka-topics",
    "value-kafka-topics",
    "--input-job-name",
    "value-job-name"
  ],
"parallelism": 30
}
' http://x.x.x.x:8081/jars/810ac968-5d5f-450d-aafc-22655238d617.jar/run
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for Python code to submit Flink job through REST API.

```
import json

url = base_url + "/jars/" + jar_id + "/run"
    myheader = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    mydata = {
        "programArgsList": [
                            "--input-kafka-server", "value-input-kafka-server",
                            "--input-kafka-topics", "value-kafka-topics",
                            "--input-job-name","value-job-name"
                            ],
        "parallelism": 30
    }
    x = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(mydata), headers=myheader)
```