# Flink REST API POST error while trying to start a new job using the uploaded jar

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to hit the [/jars/:jarid/run](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/monitoring/rest_api.html#jars-jarid-run) endpoint to start a Flink job as follows after reading up this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348050/flink-rest-api-error-request-did-not-match-expected-format-jarrunrequestbody) -

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '
{
    "programArgsList": [
        "--runner",
        "FlinkRunner",
        "--inputTopicName",
        "inputTopicNameValue",
        "--Argument",
        "Value",
        "--streaming",
        "true"]
}
' http://<JobManager-hostname>:<port>/jars/MyApplication.jar/run
```

I get the following error when I try the above command -

```
{"errors":["Internal server error.","<Exception on server side:\norg.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method 
caused an error: Argument 'FlinkRunner' does not begin with '--'\n\tat 
org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:546)\n\tat 
org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)\n\tat 
org.apache.flink.client.program.OptimizerPlanEnvironment.getOptimizedPlan(OptimizerPlanEnvironment.java:83)\n\tat 
org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgramUtils.createJobGraph(PackagedProgramUtils.java:80)
```

`Argument 'FlinkRunner' does not begin with '--'` leads me to think that argument values are not being provided correctly in my example. I understand that the Flink documentation provides the JSON schema definition and not the sample request in the [REST API docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.9/monitoring/rest_api.html#jars-jarid-run). What is the correct way to provide argument values? My example is following what the accepted solution suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348050/flink-rest-api-error-request-did-not-match-expected-format-jarrunrequestbody).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following POST request worked for me so I am documenting it here -

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '
{
    "programArgsList": [
        "--runner=FlinkRunner",
        "--inputTopicName=inputTopicNameValue",
        "--Argument=Value",
        "--streaming=true"]
}
' http://<JobManager-hostname>:<port>/jars/MyApplication.jar/run
```